# Prevent duplicate entry during data entry using php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to prevent users entering duplicate records (at least warn them) using php. The following code echoes the same code from the combo box (**Txt_Gen**) inspite of entering different values and warns of Duplicate Entry. The rows in the table is dynamically generated. So it is using the same ID, which is the root cause of the problem. Please help..

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Add rows to table //
function addRow1(tableID) 
{
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
}

var gensel = []; // array //

//getting the value of the combobox //

function myFunction1(form) 
{
var gval = document.getElementById('Txt_Gen').value; 

//var gval = form.Txt_Gen.options[form.Txt_Gen.options.selectedIndex];

var a = gensel.indexOf(gval);
//alert(a);//
if ( a==-1 ) {
gensel.push(gval);
}  else  {
alert('Duplicate Entry');  // Displays Error Message every time //
}
}

</script> 

</head>

<body>

<!-- DB Query for populating the combo box -->
<?Php $genquery= " SELECT GENCODE, DESCRIPTION FROM xxxx";?>

<!-- HTML Part -->
<div id="container">

<form action="indent_dml.php?t=R" class="register" method="POST">
<div id="Layer_Ind_Container" >

<!-- Btn_Add is used to add row to the table -->

<input type="button" id="Btn_Add" name="Btn_Add" value="Add Record"  onClick="addRow1('Table_IndNew');" /> 
<input type="submit" id="Btn_Submit" name="Btn_Submit" value="Submit" >
</div>

<table id="Table_IndNew">
<tr>
<td>
    <select name="Txt_Gen[]" size="1" id="Txt_Gen"  onchange="myFunction1(this.form)">
    <option value=''>--- Select ---</option>
    <?php $listemp = $dbo->query($genquery);
    while ($rowemp = $listemp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowemp['GENCODE']?>"><?php echo $rowemp['DESCRIPTION']?></option>
    <?php    }    ?>
    </select>
</td>

<!-- Some other elements are also present in the table such as quantity etc -->

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<!-- HTML part Ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would suggest using PDO (php data objects) to do this however I'm unsure of what you're actually trying to achieve here as you haven't given much context? is this going to connect to a database of some sort? have you managed to connect to it? if so you can do a simple count with PDO to check the databse

```
$duplicate = "SELECT COUNT(table) AS num FROM table WHERE [whatever you don't 
want to be duplicated] = :btn-add"; // where you bind the input from HTML field
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($duplicate);

  $stmt->bindValue(':btn-add', $duplicate);

  $stmt->execute();


  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  if($row['num'] > 0){
      die('That table exists already!');
  }
```

however this depends massively on what you're trying to achieve? this is how I have interpreted what you want to do, I would suggest at reading into PDO at this. [LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) Please try to be more specific with your questioning though as it's very difficult to give an answer to something that isn't clearly written

Comment: I am connecting to the database using PDO. It is a tabular entry form like an excel sheet, where the user select the data from a combobox which is being populated from the database. A new record (combobox) can be added to the form only after pressing the 'Add Record' button. Once all the entries are completed only then the user submits the form.

Comment: So you want to check when they select something from a drop down menu? I presume you are connected to the database and know how to manipulate PDO objects?

Comment: Yes..The user will select from the drop down which is dynamically populated from the database.

Comment: Then can you not just apply the principle of my answer above to it?